# Can I choose to be hit by an attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, sorcerer, touch-attacks

I'm a [Phoenix Bloodline](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/phoenix-sorcerer-bloodline/) Sorcerer. The Bloodline Arcana ability reads:

> When casting any spell that deals fire damage, you can instead heal your targets. The spell deals no damage, and living creatures affected by the spell instead regain a number of hit points equal to half the fire damage the spell would normally deal.

Which sounds great. I know that if I use a Fireball, there is a rule that lets my party "fail" their saving throws:

> [Voluntarily Giving up a Saving Throw](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Saving-Throw)
> A creature can voluntarily forgo a saving throw and willingly accept a spell’s result. Even a character with a special resistance to magic can suppress this quality.

However, I can't find a rule that lets them be "hit" by a spell like [Scorching Ray](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scorching-ray/) (which requires a ranged touch attack) when they choose to. Is there any official rule to enable this?

Comment: What distinction are you making between "RAW" and "supplementary"? If the supplement is an official part of the rule set, doesn't that make it "RAW"?

Comment: Actually I think that I considered supplementary like dev comments, but I also included that... I blame the fact I hadn't had coffee. Lemme edit for clarity.

Comment: Stand over they while they are unarmored, prone, tied up, and paralyzed, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your main question "Can I choose to be hit by an attack" is **yes, you can.**

The answer to your other question "Can I automatically hit an ally with a ranged attack/ranged touch attack" is no, you can't. **You must roll the ranged attack/ ranged touch attack**.

The rule to understand this are described on Touch spell in combat and ranged touch spell in combat as you can see below.

> Touch Spells in Combat: Many spells have a range of touch. To use these spells, you cast the spell and then touch the subject.[...] **You can automatically touch one friend or use the spell on yourself**, but to touch an opponent, you must succeed on an attack roll.

As you can see this is specified and since specific overrule generic this means it is an exception.

Now read ranged touch spell in combat:

> Ranged Touch Spells in Combat: Some spells allow you to make a ranged touch attack as part of the casting of the spell. These attacks are made as part of the spell and do not require a separate action. Ranged touch attacks provoke an attack of opportunity, even if the spell that causes the attacks was cast defensively. Unless otherwise noted, ranged touch attacks cannot be held until a later turn.

As you can see there is not specified that you can automatically hit an ally and therefore you simply must roll a ranged touch attack to land the spell against your ally.

As a personal opinion, anyway, ***if*** your ally want to be hitted by your attack he can remove his dex bonus (and other bonus like dodge etc etc).

Comment: I guess that'd work on Touch of Combustion (and the interaction with catching fire by a spell changed by this effect is a whole other story). So I'm guessing pushing for a house rule would be the only option left for things like Scorching Ray.

Comment: For ranged attacks (touch or normal) you must come up with an HR yes. I want to clarify that, RAW, you can not automatically hit an ally with your sword too and I'm pretty sure even if you want to be hit by a monster the monster must make an attack roll and, if he roll 1 (for example) he will fail...but your question is about ranged attacks and not melee.

Comment: Spell melee touch attacks are definitely included, even if I didn't specifically mention them. And I hadn't looked at those rules in this light yet, so that's definitely a good find.

Comment: While it's not mentioned RAW, it makes total sense from both in-world and game-mechanics perspectives to be able to _at minimum_ choose to use your flat-footed AC - that is, no attempt to dodge or avoid an attack.  Personally, I'd allow a PC who wanted to be hit by an attack the option to use flat-footed AC _and_ apply their Dexterity bonus as a penalty to their AC as well, representing trying to move _into_ the attack.